# Test Automation Using Python

Tags: python, automated-tests, token

I have written following code to generate Token, file saved as token.py

```
import requests
import unittest

class RestTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_token(requests):
        response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/auth/token', auth=('signant', 'hello'))
        data = response.json()

        if response.status_code == 200 and data["status"] == "SUCCESS":
            token = data["token"]
        else:
            token = None
            print("The request was not successful.")
        print(token)
        return token
```

and used following command  to run the  test `python -m token.py` but nothing happens, what is wrong there ?

Br

Sara

Comment: While I'm not even sure if a fixure can be defined in a class, I am sure you need to use it somewhere in a test to get it executed.

Comment: @KlausD. I have actually tried different options, first I only tried with def and not class or fixture was added. nothing happens even if I remove fixture or pytest both

Comment: But where are you **using** the fixture?

Comment: @KlausD. ok I have updated my question